# Finding time difference from different records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have database table which records Biometric data, for when USER ENTER/Leave office by swapping finger over it.

fields:

```
USERID EmpName, InOutTime, InOutDate
```

now when user enters office then it records

```
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|USERID|EmpName|InOutTime|InOutDate|
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|001   |John   |08:30    |12-12-13 | //When user enters office
+------+-------+---------+---------+
|001   |John   |04:30    |12-12-13 | //When user leaves office
+------+-------+---------+---------+
```

Now only time changes each time but i want to find time difference (total work hours), from both records and show it then.

Caution: accidently user record can get enter more than once.

Comment: Why are you storing date and time separately? What do you want to happen when there is a row for start time but not for finish time? What about the opposite? What if the time spans a date? The current schema makes it extremely difficult to accurately represent in and out times when there is nothing to enforce that both exist, or any of their attributes.

Comment: acutally comapny needs it this way

Comment: i argued but they say that it should be this way

Comment: May be you want to run a query to fix the data if errors exist before you run the report.

Comment: I think you should have another Column in this table maybe a Bit column which indicates whether it is an `InTime` Record or `OutTime` Record.

Comment: Please explain what to do in situations where you might have IN, IN, OUT, IN, OUT, OUT, OUT, IN for the same employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Your Data**

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE
 (USERID VARCHAR(10),EmpName VARCHAR(10),InOutTime TIME,InOutDate DATE)
 INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES
('001','John','08:30','12-12-13'),('001','John','04:30','12-12-13'),
('002','Sam','05:30','12-12-13'),('002','Sam','04:30','12-12-13')
```

**Query**

```
SELECT    t1.EmpName
        , t1.InOutTime AS InTime
        , t2.InOutTime AS [TimeOut]
        , t1.InOutDate AS [DateVisited]
        , DATEDIFF(HOUR,t1.InOutTime, t2.InOutTime) TotalHours
FROM  @TABLE t1 INNER JOIN @TABLE t2
ON    t1.USERID = t2.USERID 
AND   t1.InOutDate = t2.InOutDate
AND   t1.InOutTime < t2.InOutTime
```

**Result Set**

```
╔═════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════╦════════════╗
║ EmpName ║      InTime      ║     TimeOut      ║ DateVisited ║ TotalHours ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════╬════════════╣
║ John    ║ 04:30:00.0000000 ║ 08:30:00.0000000 ║ 2013-12-12  ║          4 ║
║ Sam     ║ 04:30:00.0000000 ║ 05:30:00.0000000 ║ 2013-12-12  ║          1 ║
╚═════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════╩════════════╝
```

Comment: thanks but i only have one table, u mentioned 2 tables, T1, T2, it confused me

Comment: @user3207757 I am joining the table to itself to separate intime and outtime

Comment: ok i don't understand this part: AND t1.InOutDate = t2.InOutDate
AND   t1.InOutTime < t2.InOutTime

Comment: @user3207757 ok this the condition I am joining the table to itself, 1st I used two different Aliases t1 and t2 for same table to join it to itself. in on cluase I am saying join the table where Data is same AND t1.INouttime is less than the t2.InoutTime AND Employee name is the same. In this way All the records for an employee on a certain date can be pulled together and then I have used the smaller InoutTime value as Intime and bigger InoutTime value as OutTime. took their difference and here you have your total hours that person worked/spent on site.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a marginally useful query to see how bad the data structure is:

```
;WITH x AS 
(
  SELECT UserID, EmpName, InOutTime, InOutDate,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserID ORDER BY InOutDate, InOutTime)
  FROM dbo.tablename
)
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, x.InOutTime, y.InOutTime)
  FROM x LEFT OUTER JOIN x AS y
  ON x.UserID = y.UserID AND x.rn = y.rn -1;
```

This will yield all kinds of crazy results in any case where the fingerprint wasn't scanned on the way out. This is what you get when you let non-database people design tables I guess. :-)

You really need to re-visit the design to fix the problems I outlined in my comment above.

Comment: `WHERE x.rn % 2 = 1`, to make this marginally more useful.